# Authentication Failure while accessing super-user privilege

Tags: 14.04, sudo, su

I get the root privilege when I type `sudo`.

But when `su` asks for the **Password**, which I type in, the terminal says

```
su: Authentication Failure
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Terminal By CTRL+ALT+T and Type :-

```
sudo passwd
```

And  Re-Enter your password. This command will have you change your current password.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use sudo su

```
$ sudo su
```

or sudo -i / sudo -s

```
$ sudo -i 
$ sudo -s
```

Both work fine and will do everything .

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the password of the `sudo` and login

```
$ sudo passwd    
[sudo] password for dhamu:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

After changing the `sudo passwd` you will be able to switch user via `su`

```
$ su
Password:
root@askmetutorials:/etc#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
sudo -i
```

Then just enter your password to get root privilege.